# How to set the value of a Kendo AutoComplete control to a javascript object?

Tags: javascript, autocomplete, kendo-ui, kendo-autocomplete

I have a KendoUI AutoComplete control bound to a list of objects. What I can't figure out is how to set the selected value of the AutoComplete from javascript. For example:

```
<input id="autocomplete" />
<script>
  $("#autocomplete").kendoAutoComplete({
    dataTextField: "Name",
    dataSource: [ 
      { id: 1, Name: "Apples" }, 
      { id: 2, Name: "Oranges" }, 
      { id: 3, Name: "Carrots" } ]
  });

  $("#autocomplete").data("kendoAutoComplete").value({ id: 2, Name: "Oranges" });
</script>
```

This just results in the AutoComplete control showing [object Object]. A jsBin of the problem is available here: [jsBin](http://jsbin.com/mulab/2/edit?html,output)

Any suggestions?
Jason

Comment: Use `$("#autocomplete").data("kendoAutoComplete").value("Oranges");`

Comment: Arg, I thought I'd tried that. Must have had something else wrong at the time. Thanks OnaBai! Add your comment as an answer and I'll set it as the Answer.

Answer (score 3):

Answer from OnaBai

```
$("#autocomplete").data("kendoAutoComplete").value("Oranges");
```

Comment: The `value()` method sets the string value of the widget, not the dataItem. And it's a description field rather than an ID. Basically, the AutoComplete widget lets you pick one item from an array of strings. What you pass to `value()` should be one of those strings.